# How to download a pdf file after editing it?

Tags: reactjs, pdf

I am new to React and in my project I am trying to fetch a pdf file, edit it and then download it.
To do this, I tried to use pdf-lib. The problem is that, after I make the required changes to the pdf file, it gives me an error when trying to open it: "Failed to load PDF document".

Here is my code:

```
const manageOnClickGenerate = async () => {
    const existingPdfBytes = await fetch(url).then(res => res.arrayBuffer())

    const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load(existingPdfBytes);
    ///make changes to the pdf
    const pdfBytes = await pdfDoc.save();

    const blob = new Blob(pdfBytes);
    const fileUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    let alink = document.createElement("a");
    alink.href = fileUrl;
    alink.download = "SamplePDF.pdf";
    alink.click();
  }
```

Can someone help me out, please? Thank you in advance!

I have tried more options, but what I don't understand is why it works to directly blob res, but not to edit it and then blob it.

Answer (score 0):

[`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob) expects an array so you need to change

```
const blob = new Blob(pdfBytes);
```

to

```
const blob = new Blob([pdfBytes]);
```